# Cancel a jQuery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a jQuery hover with a cancel. I have an index page that I load sub-pages into. On the index page, I call assignPopups('a img'). It is used to show a popup on the page. When I hover over an a tag it works fine. When I load a sub-page into the index page, I also call assignPopups('a') from that page, with just the a tag this time. When I hover over an item on my sub-page, the popup shows up...even if I move my mouse away before it displays. I watch the cancel event run but the popup still shows. Can someone show me how to have an effective hover that WILL NOT show the popup if I do not have my mouse over it long enough. One thing I am wondering if it is because if I go back and forth between the pages, the code will execute more than once. Can someone tell me if that is the problem and how to stop it?

```
var timerPopup;

function assignPopups(selector) {
    $(selector).hover(
        function (e) {
            if ($(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title'));
                $(this).removeAttr('title');
            }

            if ($(this).data('title')) {

                var bkgColor = $(this).closest("td").css("background-color");

                rgb2hex(bkgColor);

                if (bkgColor === null || bkgColor === undefined) {
                    bkgColor = "#4aacc5";
                }

                showPopupText(e, $(this).data('title'), bkgColor);
            }
        },
        function () {
            clearTimeout(timerPopup);
            $('div#titlePopup').remove();
        });
}


function showPopupText(e, mouseOverText, bkgColor) {
    timerPopup = setTimeout(function () {
        var html = '<div id="titlePopup" class="tooltip info" style="background-color:' + bkgColor + '; '
            + 'display: block;">'
            + '<span id="temp">' + mouseOverText + '</span>'
            + '</div>';
        $('div#titlePopup').remove();

        $('body').append(html);

        var htmlPopup = $("#titlePopup");

        $(htmlPopup).position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left top",
            of: e
        });

    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I think is because [event propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), you could check also ["Direct and delegated events
The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest, innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur all the way up to the body and the...](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the #titlePopup from id to class, this is so when `$('.titlePopup').remove();` is called it will remove all instances of this code. Also added `$('.titlePopup').remove();` right after when `showPopupText()` is called.

```
var timerPopup;
function assignPopups(selector) {
    $(selector).hover(
        function (e) {
            if ($(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title'));
                $(this).removeAttr('title');
            }

            if ($(this).data('title')) {

                var bkgColor = $(this).closest("td").css("background-color");

                rgb2hex(bkgColor);

                if (bkgColor === null || bkgColor === undefined) {
                    bkgColor = "#4aacc5";
                }

                showPopupText(e, $(this).data('title'), bkgColor);
            }
        },
        function () {
            clearTimeout(timerPopup);
            $('.titlePopup').remove();
        });
}

function showPopupText(e, mouseOverText, bkgColor) {
    //Remove all other popups.
    $('.titlePopup').remove();
    timerPopup = setTimeout(function () {
        var html = '<div class="titlePopup tooltip info" style="background-color:' + bkgColor + '; '
            + 'display: block;">'
            + '<span id="temp">' + mouseOverText + '</span>'
            + '</div>';
        $('div#titlePopup').remove();

        $('body').append(html);

        var htmlPopup = $("#titlePopup");

        $(htmlPopup).position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left top",
            of: e
        });

    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Now the popup never shows. I'm trying to see why that is.

Comment: it is probably because all your styles are assigned with #titlePopup change that to .titlePopup.

Comment: Yes, I had already noticed that and changed them with no effect.

Comment: Yours works, so I will set it as answer. It does not work for me so I must have something else getting in the way.

Comment: Why don't you create a jsfiddle then ill see if can help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116830/discussion-between-wannabe-and-jsonras).

Comment: The solution above got me most of the way there. I remembered that I had to use unbind() since I was calling the assignPopups() on every page load...on the new page when I loaded it. So, I added $('a').on('hover').unbind(); that runs on every page (or sub-page) load and then call the assignPopups().